# Fill in empty header with previous column name - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each second column name is skipped:

eg

[image]

Step_1. 
The idea is to fill unnamed columns with previous name to get:

[image]

Step_2.
To sum up "in" and "out" in each class, to get final result like this

[image]

The intermediary Step_1 is important and cannot be skipped to get the final result.

I appreciate any help and apologize for not being clear enough when asking question at the first attempt. 
Thank you

Comment: Whas is second row? data or header?

Comment: header. The idea is to sum up then 2 columns under the higher level header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Idea is convert columns to Series, so possible replace missing values instead values starting by `Unnamed` with forward filling:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().mask(lambda x: x.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill()
print (df)
  Column_1 Column_1 Column_2 Column_2
0        a        d        f        g
```

EDIT:

If missing values in index:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().ffill()
```

---

`MultiIndex` solution is necessary, if second row is header too - first use `header=[0,1]` for `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Column_1;Unnamed_column;Column_2;Unnamed_column
a;d;f;g
1;5;5;6
7;8;9;4"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=[0,1])
print (df)
  Column_1 Unnamed_column Column_2 Unnamed_column
         a              d        f              g
0        1              5        5              6
1        7              8        9              4

a = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

df.columns = [a.to_series().mask(lambda x: x.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill(), b]
print (df)
  Column_1    Column_2   
         a  d        f  g
0        1  5        5  6
1        7  8        9  4
```

Comment: I just edited the original post - instead of "Unnamed_Column" is Nan. Apologize for the confusion

Comment: @Vero - How working `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().ffill()` ?

Comment: @Vero - If still problem, is possible add sample data for next 2 rows? And add `print (df.columns.tolist())` to question?

Comment: I have edited the original post from scratch, adding some examples

Comment: Thank you for explanation, @jezrael. This is very helpful. I haven't tested yet, i will tell you later

Comment: the first part (assigning names to empty headers) works perfectly. I got stuck with the second part (multiple headers). I thought would it be simpler to delete 2nd header and then groupby and sum by column name? Is it possible?

Comment: I just grouped by column name and deleted the first row(second header)
df_new=df.groupby(df[1:].columns, axis=1).sum()
df_new=df_new.drop(df_new.index[0])

Comment: @Vero simply use df. sum(axis=1,level=0) or df. sum(axis=1,level=1)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,

```
t = pd.DataFrame(df.columns)
t.loc[t[0].str.startswith('Unnamed: '),0] = np.NaN
t[0].bfill(inplace=True)
df.columns = t[0].values
```

Create temp dataframe  with column of original dataframe. apply ffill or bfill as per your wish. assign back the values again to original dataframe.

Comment: instead of "unnamed_column" there are already NaNs. So the 2nd row in this code can be skipped, right?

Comment: @Vero - Actually it's not, It has values `Unnamed :n ! = np.NaN`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the df.index with a list comprehension.

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Column_1": [1], "Unnamed_column1": [2], "Column_2": [3], "Unnamed_column2": [4]})

cols = [[c, c] for c in df.columns[::2]]
df.columns = [_ for _ in chain(*cols)]
```

Having said that it might be better to assign unique names to columns as they will be used  keys/indices,  i.e .

```
cols = [[c, c+"_new"] for c in df.columns[::2]]
```