# Multi Index just repeats columns instead of merging them

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Val1        Val2              Val3        Val4
Row1  Row2  Row3  Row4  Row5  Row6  Row7  Row8
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

I read it as `df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=[0,1])`

That produces the following:

```
Val1  Unnamed_1 Unnamed_2  Val2   Unnamed_3 ...
Row1  Row2      Row3       Row4  Row5       ...
1     2         3          4     5          ...
```

Namely, it fills the empty headers at level 0 with "Unnamed_x". I was trying to manually correct that to get what I wanted, which is `val1` spans `Row1` and `Row2`, then `Val2` rows 3, 4, and 5, etc. For that I used the following inelegant solution:

```
tups = []

for col in df.columns:
    if "Unnamed" not in col[0]:
        tups.append(col)
        current = col[0]
    else:
        cols = (current, col[1])
        tups.append(col)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=['Vals', 'Rows'])
```

However, that simply copies the columns over, namely:

```
Val1  Val1  Val2  Val2  Val2  Val3  Val3  Val4
Row1  Row2  Row3  Row4  Row5  Row6  Row7  Row8
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

and when I call `df['Val1']`, then I, expectedly, get the error that multi index have to be unique.

I am very confused because this seems a relatively straightforward thing to do, but for some reason it isn't working. I made sure to closely follow the documentation in [the official pandas website](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html). I would appreciate if someone can help me figure out how to fix this; or even better, if there is a way to directly tell pandas that the empty columns in the header should have the same value as the value to the left of them.

Comment: `al2` or `Val2` in your second code block?

Comment: ```Val2``` Just fixed it.

Comment: Check this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701393/fill-in-empty-header-with-previous-column-name-pandas)

Comment: @ZaeroDivide I did that, but exactly the same thing happens: When I try to call ```df['Val1']``` I get the error: ```ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!```, which makes sense since currently the columns are being rewritten, but not shared. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a slightly different approach: reading the headers and the content and then sticking them together. No issues with the MultiIndex for me

```
headers = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Val1,,Val2,,,Val3,Val4,
Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4,Row5,Row6,Row7,Row8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"""),header=None,nrows=2)

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Val1,,Val2,,,Val3,Val4,
Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4,Row5,Row6,Row7,Row8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"""),header=None,skiprows=2)

newCols = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(headers.T.ffill())

df.columns = newCols

>>> df
0 Val1      Val2           Val3 Val4
1 Row1 Row2 Row3 Row4 Row5 Row6 Row7 Row8
2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
>>> df['Val1']
1 Row1 Row2
2    1    2
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I found I have another problem, which is the column names repeat later on, even though I set ```mangle_dupe_cols=True```. That setting does not seem to be working for every column.