# multi-level column iteration

Tags: python, dataframe, subset, multi-level

I am trying to do some coding using a multi-level excel file but not on the index but multi-level columns which is something I am doing for the first time. I am slightly above a beginner but this is proving difficult. I have spent hours and I feel there must be something I am missing.

The excel file looks like this which covers off stock prices and movements:

|  | APP |  |  |  |  | BHP |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dates | Price_last | daily_price | equal_weight_avr | volume | market_cap | Price_last | daily_price | equal_weight_avr | volume | market_cap |
| 30/03/2015 | -2.1138 | 28.1285 | 28.1708 | 5488439 | 158495.368 | -0.2722 | 91.6 | 91.4562 | 1069571 | 43057.5964 |
| 31/03/2015 | 3.0897 | 28.9976 | 28.9474 | 7356402 | 160263.7051 | 0.5677 | 92.12 | 93.0175 | 1182913 | 43200.3948 |
| 1/04/2015 | -2.2237 | 28.3528 | 28.417 | 8779128 | 157870.4531 | 0.5536 | 92.63 | 92.8784 | 768625 | 43439.5633 |
| 2/04/2015 | -0.3955 | 28.2406 | 28.2239 | 7231402 | 156288.6287 | 0.7449 | 93.32 | 93.4177 | 721347 | 43763.1442 |
| 3/04/2015 | -0.3955 | 28.2406 | 28.2239 | 7231402 | 156288.6287 | 0.7449 | 93.32 | 93.4177 | 721347 | 43763.1442 |
| 6/04/2015 | -0.3955 | 28.2406 | 28.2239 | 7231402 | 156288.6287 | 0.7449 | 93.32 | 93.4177 | 721347 | 43763.1442 |

I am trying to combine the first level of the stock ticker/name with the column below so it looks something like:

“APP_Price_last”, “APP_daily_price” etc. This would mean that the row of ‘Dates’ and the updated names would end up being the header/column names in the updated dataframe of course. 'Dates' would end up being the index.

Overall I just want to be able to have each stock as its own subset dataframe essentially with the various columns and relevant numbers. So far with a lot of back and forth on the coding I have made a list comprehension to replace the columns but I have encountered a problem.

```
# This is where I am stuck – combine ticker with the header/column label but must be able to have code determine when to stop so as to not replace all column labels with the same three letter stock ticker, which is what is happening with the below code:

new_columns = [str(df.columns[i]) + '_' + str(df.iloc[0, i]) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
df.columns = new_columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean by ticker. But if you want to flatten your two level columns and concatenate its values for each column:

```py
# imports excel data with dates as index, and first two rows as multi-index columns
df = pd.read_excel('~/Downloads/book1.xlsx', header=(0,1), index_col=0)
# flattens multi-index columns with join with underscore separator
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df]
```

would do.

Comment: Hi Learning is a mess,
I have tried the above it seems to result in a just an underscore being added in between every letter in the column name:

A_P_P_P_r_i_c_e_l_a_s_t

As far as I can tell the dataframe is not multi-index when checking directly in python.

'Ticker' is the financial term for three letters of a company share.

There should be no 'Unnamed' columns the header should look as follows:

"Dates" (index column), "APP_Price_last", "APP_daily_price", etc and there are other share names so along the column label row it switches to "BHP_Price_last", "BHP_daily_price" etc.

Comment: could you please share the values of `df.columns` with us?

Comment: No problems I added the table as per excel in the question above

Comment: Have edited my answer. I found it easier to read the first two rows as columns at import time and then transform these multi-index to a single level. Dates are an index here, you can map them into a column easily.

Answer (score 0):

Based in part on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701755/3957794) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701393/fill-in-empty-header-with-previous-column-name-pandas) and on this [Medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-multiindex-columns-and-rows-in-pandas-f5406c50e569).

Read in csv using the following:

`df = pd.read_csv('stock_test.txt', sep='|',skipinitialspace=True, header=[0,1])`

(used `sep='|'` becaused I read the data from `markdown`)

```
first = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
second = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
df.columns = [first.to_series().mask(lambda x: x.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill(), second]
```

Reset `DataFrame` with the combined column-names:

`df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()`